# Exception Handling in Web API and return JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the controller of a Web API which queries the DB and returns result in JSON is like below,

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails(string ROOM, DateTime DOB_GT)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ROOM))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(new { error = "Input paramete cannot be Empty or NULL" });
        }

        try
        {
            List<OracleParameter> prms = new List<OracleParameter>();
            List<string> selectionStrings = new List<string>();
            prms.Add(new OracleParameter("ROOM", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ROOM, ParameterDirection.Input));
            prms.Add(new OracleParameter("DOB_GT", OracleDbType.Date, DOB_GT, ParameterDirection.Input));
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TBaseConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
            {
                DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
                var strQuery = "SELECT * from RESULTS_VW where ROOM = :ROOM and DOB > :DOB_GT";
                var returnObject = new { data = new OracleDataTableJsonResponse(connStr, strQuery, prms.ToArray()) };
                var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
                ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
                if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=TData.json", out contentDisposition))
                {
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
                }
                return response;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
         {   var returnObj = new { error = ex.Message };
             var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, returnObj, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
             ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
             if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=error.json", out contentDisposition))
             {
                 response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
             }
             return response;
         }
     }
    }
```

And the API works perfectly for the valid Query parameters. But I am trying to implement error handling when there are any exception in the API it has to return a JSON like `{"error":" Exception Message"}`. In the above code I have the catch block to handle the exception. But it is not returning anything if there is any exception. Please suggest me a simple way of constructing JSON on exception. 
    [image]

Comment: In case of error suggest to return `500. Internal server error` response. You can use `ApiController.InternalServerError` method for this. `return this.InternalServerError(ex);`

Comment: @Fabio Do I use them in the catch block.

Comment: You can use them there. And `return this.Ok(returnObject)` can be used for successful response

Comment: Doesn't Web API detects header and return response accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a generic response class to simplify the communication model. For this you will have;

- Generic Response class (common response object)
- Domain response model (class containing your logics)

See code below:

1. GenericResponse.cs

   ```
   public class GeneicResponse<T>
   { 
       private Response(){}

       public Response(T data)
       {
           this.Data = data;
           this.Error = String.Empty;
       }

       public Response(Exception ex)
       {
           this.Data = default(T);
           this.Error = ex.Message;
       }

       public T Data { get; set; }
       public string Error { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. DomainModel.cs

   ```
   public class DomainModel
   {
       public int                      ID      { get; set; }
       public string                   Name    { get; set; }


       public DomainModel() { }

       public DomainModel(int id)
       {
           //populate object properties from database here
       }
   }
   ```
3. Your controller class:

   ```
   [Route("api/myApiMethod")]
   public Response<DomainModel> GetDetails(string ROOM, DateTime DOB_GT)
   {
       try
       {
           DomainModel myDomainModel   = new DomainModel(ROOM, DOB_GT);
           return new Response<DomainModel>(myDomainModel);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           return new Response<DomainModel>(ex);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use a dictionary to hold message and exception.

Do import

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Then

```
Dictionary<string, string> dr = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dr.Add("some Message as key", ex.Message);
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dr, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
```

hope this helps

Comment: Errors out as `'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>' does not contain a definition for 'add' and no extension method 'add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` I did add the namespace as `using System.Collections.Generi`

Comment: @trx using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: That was a mistake while pasting I have already using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: Yes I do have both the namespaces `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;` but still getting the same error

Comment: add should be "Add". did some typo.  Dictionary<string, string> dr = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dr.Add("some Message as key", ex.Message);

Comment: Thanks. But the issue is that it is not returning the JSON as a file when I call the URL with mistake in the browser.I added the image of what I get